# RabbitMQ asynchronous support

Tags: c#, asynchronous, rabbitmq

Does the RabbitMQ .NET client have any sort of asynchronous support? I'd like to be able to connect and consume messages asynchronously, but haven't found a way to do either so far.

*(For consuming messages I can use the EventingBasicConsumer, but that's not a complete solution.)*

Just to give some context, this is an example of how I'm working with RabbitMQ at the moment (code taken from my blog):

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };

using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare("testqueue", true, false, false, null);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += Consumer_Received;
        channel.BasicConsume("testqueue", true, consumer);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be a little more specific? what do you mean by "asynchronous" in this case? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: async/await... so I'm looking for equivalents that are awaitable and return a task, like System.IO has e.g. ConnectAsync(), ReadAsync(), etc.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Rabbit supports dispatching to asynchronous message handlers using the `AsyncEventingBasicConsumer` class. It works similarly to `EventingBasicConsumer`, but allows you to register a callback which returns a `Task`. The callback is dispatched to and the returned `Task` is awaited by the RabbitMQ client.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
    HostName = "localhost",
    DispatchConsumersAsync = true
};

using(var connection = cf.CreateConnection())
{
    using(var channel = conn.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare("testqueue", true, false, false, null);

        var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(model);

        consumer.Received += async (o, a) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message Get" + a.DeliveryTag);
            await Task.Yield();
        };
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I can't quite pinpoint which release this was added in, but the relevant commits are from February 2017.

Comment: Seems like it's been available since 5.0.0-pre3.

Comment: @Gigi Do we have async support for Producer?

Comment: @Pingpong not that I know of.

Comment: Take a look to https://gist.github.com/kjnilsson/732c0883c7807647e84ba5be2c3027f5

Answer (score 13):

there is no async/await support built in to the RabbitMQ .NET client at this point. There is an open ticket for this on the [RabbitMQ .NET Client repository](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/83)

Comment: This is really ridiculous after all these years for such a popular platform....

Answer (score 5):

To summarize current `async`/`TPL` support:

- As @paul-turner mentioned, there is now an `AsyncEventingBasicConsumer` which you can register events for and return a `Task`.
- There is also an [`AsyncDefaultBasicConsumer`](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/main/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/api/AsyncDefaultBasicConsumer.cs) for which you can override virtual methods such as `HandleBasicDeliver` and return a `Task`. Original PR [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/pull/307) (looks like it was also introduced in 5.0?)
- Per the final comments on the above PR and [this issue](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/83), it looks like they are working on a new, from-scratch .NET client which would more fully support `async` operations, but I don't see any specific links to that effort.

Answer (score 4):

There is `AsyncEventingBasicConsumer` and all that it does, is `await`ing your async "event handlers" when message is received. That's the only thing that is made asynchronous here. Typically you don't get any profits from this, because you have only one "handler". Messages are still processed one-by-one. They are processed **synchronously**! Also you lose control of exception handling because awaiting is done  inside Consumer.

Let me guess that by **asynchronous** message processing you mean some degree of parallelism.

What I ended up using is `ActionBlock` from TPL Dataflow. `ActionBlock` runs as much tasks as you configured it to, managing awaits and parellelism. Since it operates on Tasks, not Threads, it can manage with less resources, as long as they are truly asynchronous.

1. Regular `EventingBasicConsumer` calls `actionBlock.Post(something)`.
2. For parallel processing you need to tell RMQ to send you N messages before you `ack` them: `model.BasicQos(0, N, true);`
3. ActionBlock has options with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property which also needs to be set to N.
4. ActionBlock runs `async Task`s which receive data posted earlier by Consumer. Tasks should not throw because ActionBlock stops all processing on exceptions.
5. Be careful to pass `CancellationToken` around and correctly wait for ActionBlock to finish all running Tasks: `actionBlock.Complete(); await actionBlock.Completion;`

Comment: As of today thats not true. I tested this yesterday and also code outside of the event handler is executed when an await is met inside the event handler.