# How to publish and receive messages asynchronously with the official RabbitMQ Client?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq

In many client like:

- [MassTransit](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit)
- [EasyNetQ](http://easynetq.com)
- [RawRabbit](https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit)

There is a way to publish and receive messages asynchronously.

I was wondering how to do the with same the [official RabbitMQ Client](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client)?

Note: So far I only found [a way to receive messages asynchronously on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47694632/4636721)

[EDIT]

In EasyNetQ this is how it is achieved:

- [Publishing](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/0a7c7fa9b96e84d7c5fea73a4b9821c473ffe8e2/Source/EasyNetQ/Producer/DefaultPubSub.cs#L79)
- [Consuming](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/7d207da792b4a84886fdfd0074a2a3d06b2061ea/Source/EasyNetQ/RabbitAdvancedBus.cs#L217)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/DtMCoixBt90

Comment: @PedroPerez how does this relate to my question?

Comment: I have search before and it seems that RabbitMQ client does not provide an asynchronous version.

Comment: @PedroPerez wondering how those libraries manage to provide an `async` `await`API

Comment: ASYNCHRONOUS RABBITMQ CONSUMERS IN .NET http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/asynchronous-rabbitmq-consumers-in-net/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193153/discussion-between-pedro-perez-and-ehouarn-perret).

Comment: @PedroPerez you should provide the cached version

Comment: @PedroPerez fair enough I will dig the source code of MassTransit and others to figure out how they achieved to provide an asynchronous API

Comment: @PedroPerez it's doable: for publishing check EasyNetQ async implementation which leverages the official RabbitMQ .NET Client => https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/7d207da792b4a84886fdfd0074a2a3d06b2061ea/Source/EasyNetQ/RabbitAdvancedBus.cs#L217

Comment: @PedroPerez and for publishing: https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/0a7c7fa9b96e84d7c5fea73a4b9821c473ffe8e2/Source/EasyNetQ/Producer/DefaultPubSub.cs#L79